# php timestamp returns 2147483647

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm using strtotime function in my php to add timestamp to each record but the problem is the timestamp output is always 2147483647. is there any configuration for timestamp that I'm missing ?
here is my php code for this part :

```
$timestamp = strtotime("now");
```

does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Use `date()` to format the timestamp: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Fix your system date? Recompile PHP? From the little information given, this doesn't seem reproducible or answerable.

Comment: (no english) 2147483647 = max value for Int in 32bits OS, check date and time in your PC, because that value is **19 January 2038**

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez my PC date and time is synchronized also my xampp virtual server time zone is set up but It's still give me this timestamp

Comment: try to print time() or strtotime("now") in a single file without another code

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez in another file with just echo time(); it's working fine that returned 1551010675

Comment: @ShakibKarami then maybe you are changing your system date before this code?

Comment: There's no `echo $timestamp` in the code in the question. Do you do something with or to the $timestamp variable before using it?

Answer (score 1):

if you need only timestamp just use it :

```
$timestamp = time();
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question or address the problem (getting allways the same (future) timestamp) at all.

Comment: this also returning 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

try to set the default timezone to use. (Available since PHP 5.1)

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

after that try

```
$timestamp = time();
```